# how to make filters with $scope variables inside controllers of directives

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have found lot of conventions to write code in angular JS. I am using the following convention.

```
app.directive("employeeList" , function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'E' , 
        templateUrl: 'employee-list.html',
        controller:function($scope , $filter)
        {
            $scope.emp_positions = positions_json; // my FIREST array
            $scope.emp_users_json = users_json; // My SECOND Array
          //My Code Logic // 

         // I WANT TO MAKE FILTER HERE WHICH CAN USE $SCOPE VARIABLE. 
         IS THERE ANY WAY TO MAKE FILTER HERE LIKE
            $SCOPE.FILTER('FLITER_NAME' , FUNCTION($SCOPE)){....} ???
          IS IT POSSIBLE? IF NOT WHAT COULD BE OTHER POSSIBLE WAY.
     //

         },
      controllerAs: 'emp'  
      };
 });
```

Now I want to write the custom filter for filtering my data which is now in "$scope" variable.
1)Can I write the custom filter inside controller which uses $scope variable. If yes, Then how Please give me example.
if not then what else I can do to pass the $scope variable to the custom variable which is outside the Directive.?

http://plnkr.co/edit/J0xCIP9d5boJzostGEv8?p=preview

I have added my plunker please read in table "POSITION HERE" nad also read my script.js file. and for the data i have added data.js file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

About using of $scope into the filter.

1) You would pass scope variables from directive to the filter as function parameter and get access to them from `args` object:

```
 app.directive("employeeList" , function(){
        return {
            restrict : 'E' , 
            templateUrl: 'employee-list.html',
            controller:function($scope)
            {
               $scope.emp_positions = positions_json;
               $scope.emp_users_json = users_json;

               //your another code here
            },
            controllerAs: 'emp'  
          };
    });
```

Your `employee-list.html`

```
<div ng-repeat="employee in employees | employeeFilter: [emp_positions, emp_users_json]">
 .....
</div>
```

Your filter:

```
app.filter('employeeFilter', function () {
    return function (input, args) {
       console.log(args[0]); //$scope.emp_positions here
       console.log(args[1]); //$scope.emp_users_json here

       var inputArray = input;
       return inputArray;
    }
});
```

2) You would pass whole $scope to the filter by passing `this`.

`this` will be a reference to current scope.

```
<div ng-repeat="employee in employees | employeeFilter: this">
     .....
</div>
```

Your filter:

```
app.filter('employeeFilter', function () {
    return function (input, args) {
       console.log(args[0]); //whole $scope from directive here

       var inputArray = input;

       return inputArray; //returned value from filter 
       // in this case returned array equals to the initial input
    }
});
```

P.S. But I suggest to choose the first option and pass only scope variables, not whole $scope.

I've updated your plunker.

Please see: [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UCxIfd9YX8LSsQdONIEK?p=preview).

Comment: how to use $scope variable inside this filter

Comment: @ShivekParmar, you can use $scope.variables in the filter from **args** object. See my update.

Comment: but I have to different arrays inside my scope variable. I want to display find a record inside the first and also the same record inside the second with different key. But according to your solution If I use app.filter() out the directive then it would not be able to access complete $scope varibale. since it is out side the controller. and for the record  I also do not prefer your second solution.

Comment: I am trying to use {{employee in employees | employeeFilter:(empid)" }} but since other array which contain empid is only accessible to scope. I have updated my question for more clarification.

Comment: @ShivekParmar, Could you create JSFiddle or Plunker with your example? Because I'm not quite clear what you want.

Comment: @ShivekParmar, please, see my new update of answer. You can use $scope variable into the filter, which declared and assigned in directive's controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63108/discussion-between-shivek-parmar-and-artyom-pranovich).

Comment: I have added my code in plunker please see my question again.

Comment: @ShivekParmar, I hope, that it's what do you want?

Comment: Prnovich , I appreciate your effort and your solution is good but I want a different kind of solution.Please see my updated plunker and do read the HTML comments.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I write the custom filter inside controller which uses $scope variable.

Yes, you can by write `.filter()` on user list.

*JS*

```
 /*
    load all users and filter them according to condition
 */
 $scope.getUsers = function(){
            return $scope.emp_users_json.users
 .filter(function(item)
    {            
       var itemDoesMatch = true;

       // write logic here to filter your stuff

        return itemDoesMatch;
    });
}
```

*HTML in employee-list*

```
 <tr ng-repeat="empdata in getUsers()">
```

Demo:  <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EyZ8S9WnnYCs8NdyEjeT?p=preview)</kbd>

FYI, its not good practice to call list in `ng-repeat` as method (in my case `getUsers()`) but that approach does the trick.

---

But you can try to implement the same logic by clone-filter user list, like:

```
$scope.filteredUserList = angular.copy($scope.emp_users_json.users)
 .filter(function(item)
    {            
       var itemDoesMatch = true;

       // write logic here to filter your stuff

        return itemDoesMatch;
    });
```

put it into function `foo()` and fire some watcher that will call `foo()` on any change.

In this case *HTML*: `<tr ng-repeat="empdata in filteredUserList">`